# How to embed fonts with PDKFit and asset pipeline in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, pdfkit

Until I started using PDFKit to create PDFs from HTML in Rails, I was successfully embedding Google Fonts like this:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700'
```

However, PDFKit was not embedding fonts in my PDFs. It generated the PDFs and formatted the using my print stylesheet, but using regular fonts, not my embedded ones.

So, I put EOT, WOFF, TTF and SVG versions of each font in `/app/assets/fonts` and switched to this format in a new font stylesheet called by my screen and print stylesheets:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'rokkittregular';
    src: font-url('rokkitt-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: local('rokkittregular')
         font-url('rokkitt-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         font-url('rokkitt-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         font-url('rokkitt-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         font-url('rokkitt-regular-webfont.svg#rokkittregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}
```

Again, this worked just fine for my regular HTML pages. Again, PDFKit didn't embed the fonts in my PDFs.

Assuming this probably has something to do with PDFKit not being able to find the fonts, I created a separate print-fonts stylesheet to be embedded in my print stylesheet. In it, I switched to this notation:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "rokkittregular";
    src: url("/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: url("/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.svg#rokkittregular") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}
```

And later to this notation:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "rokkittregular";
    src: url("#{Rails.root}/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: url("#{Rails.root}/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("#{Rails.root}/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("#{Rails.root}/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("#{Rails.root}/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.svg#rokkittregular") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}
```

Still it didn't work.

The strange thing is if you point your browser at `http://localhost:5000/assets/rokkitt-regular-webfont.eot`, it takes you to the font file.

How can I get these fonts working in PDFKit?

Comment: Which of the above url methods worked in the end? Having the same issue, and hoping you could update this answer ;)

Comment: The first. But since then I've switched to using DocRaptor and embedding my fonts in the stylesheet as Base64. Cheers.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for taking the time to update the answer. Looks like Base64 is the best way forward.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't mention anything about Base64. Can this be clarified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change how I called the fonts in my print stylesheet:

```
h1 {font-family: "rokkittregular";}
```

not

```
h1 {font-family: "Rokkitt", serif;}
```